# Returning a BOOL method inside a block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, grand-central-dispatch

I have this bool method that returns a yes or no for an inputted string.
I'm successfully able to return a `YES` or a `NO`, but I cannot seem to able to make a network connection and return a `YES` or a `NO` depending on the server's response.
I tried using `__block` and I don't feel like that will wait for the web request to finish, is there a way to return `YES` or `NO` in the success block without it giving me the error:

> Incompatible block pointer types sending 'BOOL(^)(NSURLSessionTask*__strong, NSError *__strong' to parameter of the type 'void(^)(NSURLSessionTask*...)

```
-(BOOL)customResponseForString:(NSString *)text {

  __block BOOL response_available;

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager.responseSerializer setAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"]];
    [manager GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/response.php?input=%@", text] parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

        NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        response_available = (BOOL)response[@"response_available"];
        if (response_available) {
            [session sendTextSnippet:response[@"response"] temporary:NO scrollToTop:NO dialogPhase:@"Summary"];
        } else {
            response_available = NO;
        }

        [session sendTextSnippet:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] temporary:NO scrollToTop:NO dialogPhase:@"Summary"];

        [session sendRequestCompleted];

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        //return NO;
    }];
 });

return response_available;

}
```

Comment: You can't do what you want here. The call to `return` at the end of the `customResponseForString:` method will be made long before any of the code in the `dispatch_async` is even started let alone long before either the `success` or `failure` blocks are ever called.

Comment: Is there any work around you can help me think of... I'm stuck...

Answer (score 1):

Your block definition syntax is probably erroneous, because you can definitely return a BOOL along other parameters in a block.

```
- (void)fetchCurrentUserWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL success, User *user))completion;
```

This method would be called like this:

```
[self.userProfileController fetchCurrentUserWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, User *user) {
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"Current User Name: %@", user.fullName);
    }
}];
```

If you use AFNetworking, check the `AFHTTPRequestOperation` object that handle completionBlocks:

```
[requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    User *user = [self userFromResponseObject:responseObject];   
    if (completion) completion(YES, user);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    if (completion) completion(NO, user);
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are implicitly initializing `response_available` to `NO` and then using an async GCD call, your method as written will always immediately return `NO` without waiting for the request to finish.  Note: switching to `dispatch_sync` won't help either because AFNetworking will queue the GET request asynchronously either way.

---

**Best Approach**

Add a completion block argument to `customResponseForString:`.  Then simply execute your completion block in the success or failure blocks of the `AFHTTPRequestOperation`.

---

**Workable Approach** (use caution!)

It is possible to make `customResponseForString:` wait for a response to the network request, but you will have significant issues if it is ever called from the main thread.

First you create a dispatch group and tell it you are starting some long-running work:

```
dispatch_group_t networkGroup = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_group_enter(networkGroup);
```

Then you need to make your network request and when it completes tell the group that the work is finished with `dispatch_group_leave()`:

```
[manager GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/response.php?input=%@", text] parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

    NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    response_available = (BOOL)response[@"response_available"];
    if (response_available) {
        [session sendTextSnippet:response[@"response"] temporary:NO scrollToTop:NO dialogPhase:@"Summary"];
    } else {
        response_available = NO;
    }

    [session sendTextSnippet:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] temporary:NO scrollToTop:NO dialogPhase:@"Summary"];

    [session sendRequestCompleted];

    dispatch_group_leave(networkGroup);

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    response_available = NO;
    dispatch_group_leave(networkGroup);
}];
```

Before your original method returns, tell it to wait for the entire group to finish processing:

```
dispatch_group_wait(networkGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
return response_available;
```

You could adjust this time interval as needed or leave it at `DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER` to let the network request time out on its own.